# How to prevent setting 2 properties together from calling a method twice

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 2 properties on a ViewModel: DateFrom and DateTo.

I want to call RefreshProducts() whenever one of them is changed **(eg. by end user or programmatically)**, and this has been achieved as follows:

```
public DateTime? DateFrom
{
    get { return _dateFrom; }
    set
    {
        _dateFrom = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DateFrom");
        RefreshProducts();
    }
}
public DateTime? DateTo
{
    get { return _dateTo; }
    set
    {
        _dateTo = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DateTo");
        RefreshProducts();
    }
}
private void RefreshProducts()
{
    //...
}
private void SetThisWeek()
{
    DateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
    DateTo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(6-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
}
```

However, my problem lies in the fact that if both properties are changed together (for example the SetThisWeek() method), RefreshProducts is being called twice; once for each property, as you would expect.

My question is this: **what is the best way to prevent the both properties from calling RefreshProducts() when they are set simultaneously, such as in the SetThisWeek() method?**

I have tried using a bool to help manage this, for example...

```
bool CanRefresh = true;

public DateTime? DateFrom
{
    get { return _dateFrom; }
    set
    {
        _dateFrom = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DateFrom");
        if (CanRefresh) RefreshProducts();
    }
}
public DateTime? DateTo { ... }
private void RefreshProducts() { ... }
private void SetThisWeek()
{
    CanRefresh = false;
    DateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
    DateTo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(6-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
    CanRefresh = true;
    RefreshProducts();
}
```

This works fine, however I'm not a fan of using a bool in this way, and I also dislike the "noise" code that is required to work it. Managing the bool allows for potential bugs when the program is modified in the future... I'm looking for a much neater way of handling this.

Comment: why cant `SetThisWeek` set the backing fields and then call the updater itself once?

Comment: that does not invalidate the suggestion, the UI/user would still trigger an unpdate thru the setters

Comment: You could just check the `CanRefresh` inside of RefreshProducts, so you don't have to update every setter.

Comment: @Plutonix Ah right, my misunderstanding... This would definitely work but I'm not a fan of calling the RaisePropertyChanged after each assignment of the two properties... I guess I could just make a method that handles this all though, which is no big deal I think

Comment: What GUI you using here? It would be helpful to know whether it's Winforms, WPF, or something else, as the binding mechanisms are different in each. In any case, it should be possible to abstract the property value storage further than just the property setters, allowing `SetThisWeek()` to access the storage in a way that updates the UI on programmatic changes while still preserving the binding.

Comment: Peter, the UI is WPF, sorry I forgot to tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your best two options are:

1. Live with it. Without seeing what `RefreshProducts()` does, it's not clear how bad it is to call it twice. But in other similar scenarios I'm used to seeing, it's not generally a huge problem.
2. Provide a setter method that takes both values as parameters and which sets both "atomically" (in the sense of your refresh).

I.e.

```
public void SetDatesFromAndTo(DateTime? from, DateTime? to)
{
    // Update private values here

    // Then...
    RefreshProducts();
}
```

Note that your `SetThisWeek()` method essentially is this mechanism, though currently it sets the properties directly instead of the backing fields.

I understand from your added detail that you are concerned about preserving the user's ability to update the properties individually. But that is not hard to achieve. Your aggregate setter (e.g. a `SetDatesFromAndTo()` method like I show, or your `SetThisWeek()`) can raise property-changed events just as easily as the property setter can. So instead of setting the properties, set the backing field and raise the events.

Comment: My belated thanks, your answer helped me achieve my goal. For some reason I had developed the impression that modifying the backing fields of bound properties wasn't good practice because of the potential for the view/view model to go out of sync if I forgot to call the property changed method after changes.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a good reason you can't update the private backing fields in your `SetThisWeek` method?:-

```
public DateTime? DateFrom
{
    get { return _dateFrom; }
    set
    {
        _dateFrom = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DateFrom");
        RefreshProducts();
    }
}

public DateTime? DateTo
{
    get { return _dateTo; }
    set
    {
        _dateTo = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DateTo");
        RefreshProducts();
    }
}

private void SetThisWeek()
{
    _dateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
    RaisePropertyChanged("DateFrom");

    _dateTo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(6-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
    RaisePropertyChanged("DateTo");

    RefreshProducts();
}
```

Or, if repeating the `RaisePropertyChanged` invocations offends you (it offends me!), you could look into using AoP to do it automatically (e.g. [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged) or [Mono.Cecil](http://joseoncode.com/2011/01/09/notifypropertyweaver-the-new-killer-for-inotifypropertychanged/)). That'd be a pretty hardcore solution for this simple example - IL weaving isn't for the fainthearted! - but it can help simplify things in a more realistic scenario.

Comment: Not really, it's similar to the solution I came up in terms of extra code required, but that could be captured into a pretty simple method, now that I think on it...